# ID потока преобразовать в переменную

Tags: c++

Подскажите пожалуйста возможно ли извлечь ID потока в переменную ?

Что то типа такого:

```
#include <thread>

int main()
{
 size_t id_thread = std::this_thread::get_id();
 size_t id_thread_ = (size_t)std::this_thread::get_id();
}
```

Оба варианта естественно не работают.

Comment: Так ведь это *дело реализации*, в каком виде хранить id потока, и совсем не факт, что он будет `int`. `auto id_thread = std::this_thread::get_id();` вас устроит?

Comment: @Harry, я раньше успел))

Comment: @Qwertiy А я зато пояснение написал :)

Comment: @Harry, так я не против того, что это дело реализации, но мне нужно ID потока преобразовать в std::string, а без преобразование в числовой тип - не совсем понятно, как это сделать.

Comment: @Harry, я не совсем корректно написал вопрос - не в переменную, а в числову. переменную. Но "Алексей Саровский" - уже дал ответ.Спасибо.

Comment: Вот уж в `string` легко, потому что для него есть оператор вывода `<<`. Заметьте, вам надо преобразовать в строку, но спросили вы совсем другое. *Когда вам нужно забить гвоздь — спрашивайте, как забить гвоздь, а не какой рукой держать при этом микроскоп...*

Comment: @Harry, да, согласен. Я просто всегда использую std::to_string().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Типы слева и справа не совпали, так что либо применить корректный тип, либо, если действительно нужен id в числовой переменной, можно сделать примерно так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    std::stringstream ss;

    ss << std::this_thread::get_id();

    int id;
    ss >> id;

    std::cout << id;
}
```

Comment: Какой кошмар. И мы еще удивляемся, что никаких гигагерцев для "нормальной работы" не хватает...

Comment: @avp Никто же не спорит, что такой код тащить в продакшн не надо, а для экспериментов иногда почему бы не сделать на коленке неоптимально (весьма популярный в этих вопросах подход: вывести в поток, потом из него же прочитать)? Порой вообще какие-то идеи проверяю на питоне, например. Прижилась - можно переносить и оптимизировать. А какое Вы решение предлагаете?

Comment: А вы не поняли. Я не про код, а про идеи, воплощениями которых вас кормят. Конкретное проявление -- это скрытое до невозможности целое число (или адрес, что по сути одно и то же)

Comment: Для этого есть язык Си, так что я бы не согласился с тем, что инкапсулировать внутреннее строение - это плохо. Касательно C++ и его новых возможностей - очень часто, например, использую не enum, а enum class, который дисциплинирует и переносит ошибки в compile-time. Это оказалось выгоднее, чем сотни define-ов и необходимость ловить ошибки в рантайме.

Comment: Ну, да. Собственно, С++ это попытка использовать тех, кто к программированию плохо способен. Как следствие, никаких гигагерцев не хватает...

Comment: Аргументация, конечно, непробиваемая

Answer (score 2):

```
auto id = std::this_thread::get_id();
```

```
std::thread::id id = std::this_thread::get_id();
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы.